# How to iterate over entity framework local items?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm using EF4.3, with DbContext.

I'm trying to view whats in the local cache, but despite a good few attempts, I still get runtime error messages.

Here's my last attempt:

```
    var entity = Uow.Context.Set<Store>().Local;
    foreach (var store in entity)
    {
        Response.Write(store.StoreId + "<br>");
    }
```

Anyone help?

Store Class

```
public partial class Store
{
    public Store()
    {
        this.Deals = new HashSet<Deal>();
        this.StoreSubcategories = new HashSet<StoreSubcategory>();
    }

    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public int StoreStatusId { get; set; }
    public int ContentSourceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Subdomain { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public string HomePage { get; set; }
    public string BackColour { get; set; }
    public string ForeColour { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ActiveFrom { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActiveUntil { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Deal> Deals { get; set; }
    public virtual Stores_Partner Stores_Partner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StoreSubcategory> StoreSubcategories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @MarkOreta - CS1061: 'Store' does not contain a definition for 'StoreId' and no extension method 'StoreId' accepting a first argument of type 'Store' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you post your model, at least your store class?  Are you sure your Store class has a StoreId property?

Comment: @MarkOreta - Added store class

Comment: @MarkOreta - Mark, thanks for your help, however i've worked it out. There was a conflict between the entity class and the store.aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Conflict between entity class and aspc page similarly named 'store'.